# How to extend a selection in vimscript

Tags: vim, select, move, extend

p.e. I have a block of text selected (using Ctrl-V) and want to extend it **in a vimscript** to a new location p.e. 30 lines below

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the markers `'<` and `'>` to move to the beginning and end respectively of the most recent visual selection. So a simple function such as

**EDITED** to use `gv` and a `jump` variable.

```
function! ExtendVisual(jump)
    execute "normal! gv" . a:jump . "j"
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> <leader>e :call ExtendVisual(30)<CR>
```

will let you extend the current visual:q region by 30 lines using <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. I created a variable "jump" which indicates how many lines the selection has to go down. What would be the function with my value "jump" inside? `normal! gv"jump"j ??

Comment: If you want to add a variable you need to explicity execute the "normal" comand, so the line would become: `execute "normal! '<V'>" . jump . "j"`. If `jump` is an argument supplied to the function, then you need to use `a:jump` when you use it.

Comment: Btw your function extend the selection as a line selection. What would it be in case of block selection?

Comment: This function is 1. Changing type of visual selection. 2. Does not work when called for the second time without quiting selection. 3. Quits visual mode when called for multiline selection with even number of lines.

Comment: 4. Extends 30 lines down from the first line of selection, not from the last. 5. I guess it relies on the (bug?) that `'>` marker is not moved during the selection: `:` in visual mode produces `:'<,'>` and thus for 3-line selection it is called three times.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my inadequate function to use `gv` which automatically re-selects the previous visual region (a new one on me!) and to use the jump variable. This way seems much neater. Thanks for the pointers, ZyX.

Comment: I still don't understand why this function, being called four times for four-line visual selection produces the same result as if it was called one time (you can add an `:echom` inside the function if you don't trust me). It looks for me like it is relying on some bug.

Comment: still found a problem with linewrap. When linewrap is on, 30j doesn't gives the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

It is better expressed with `<expr>` mappings:

```
vnoremap <expr> \e g:jump."j"
```

With a function call:

```
function Jump()
    " Do something (modifying text, switching buffers and 
    " something other is forbidden, see :h map-<expr>)
    return jump."j"
endfunction
vnoremap <expr> \e Jump()
```

Comment: thank you. Nice solution. However maybe difficult in my case...I declare the jump value in a function.

Comment: @Remonn What is the problem? You can put a function call there. See update.

Comment: In my function I calculate jump p.e. jump = 30. How would you put that in a function call?

Comment: @Remonn You can call a function that calculates jump. I can't say more without seeing this function.